# alexa sdk: saving sessionAttributes in https response

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

i have a skill and i want to load some data from an url and store it in the SessionAttributes.

so i wrote this into my `handle(handlerInput)`of my `LaunchRequestHandler`:

```
require('https').get(url, (resp) => {

  resp.on('data', (chunk) => {
    data += chunk;
  });

  resp.on('end', () => {
    let attributes = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(attributes);
    handlerInput.attributesManager.setSessionAttributes(attributes);
  });
});
```

the log shows me the correct object, but when i try to load the sessionAttributes in the next intent it's empty. I Assume it has something to do with the setSessionAttributes being in the response function, because if i set something directly after this code, it works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This might be because of the asynchronous operation. Please use async/await to make the API call and then save. Sample example,

```
const getData = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    require("https").get(url, resp => {
      resp.on("data", chunk => {
        data += chunk;
      });

      resp.on("end", () => {
        resolve(data);
      });
    });
  });
};

const LaunchRequestHandler = {
  canHandle(handlerInput) {
    return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === "LaunchRequest";
  },
  async handle(handlerInput) {
    const speechText = "welcome";
    const data = await getData(); //asynchronous operation
    const sessionAttributes = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();
    sessionAttributes.data = data;
    handlerInput.attributesManager.setSessionAttributes(sessionAttributes);
    return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechText)
      .reprompt(speechText)
      .withSimpleCard("Welcome to the Skill", speechText)
      .getResponse();
  }
};
```